# What parents enjoy is playing/play?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive

I have a question; is it better to say:

> What parents enjoy doing is playing with their children.

or:

> What parents enjoy is playing with their children.

or:

> What parents enjoy is play with their children.

Comment: The last one is not the same construction -- in the last example, _play_ is a noun, modified by _with their children_, rather than a transitivized verb _playing with_ and an object _their children_ like the first two. They're all correct, though they wouldn't have the same intonation or stress because of the different constructions. None is better than another; you shouldn't ask questions about that -- someone might give you the wrong answer, and you might believe it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still have question about the first one. Can I say: What parents enjoy doing is play with their children? Will it be a mistake?

Comment: That sentence is simply a bit awkward. Okay? Not necessarily "native-like" sounding.

Comment: @John: Granted, they're all "valid" forms. But you wouldn't often come across [*I like **play** with my {whatever}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+like+play+with+my%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) from a native speaker. There are no instances at all of that in Google Books, as compared to [*I like playing with...*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+like+playing+with+my%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) with 647 hits.

Comment: I agree with the Mr. FF.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but then compare "play is important" and "playing is important" and while the latter is found the former is more common. The statement here being about the value of play/playing makes the overall meaning closer to this than your example. With the queried forms being closer to those in meaning but closer to yours in form, I'd say the balance of how much we might expect them is somewhere in between.

Comment: What parents enjoy is play with their children, especially compared to talk or play with other family members.

Comment: I don't like questions like this on ELU (from non-native speakers who should be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)). I *would* be interested to know more about exactly *why* we're much more likely to use the transitivized verb form as the object of ***to like***, but we're more than happy to use the simple noun when ***play*** is the *subject*. And maybe usage has changed significantly over time, which would also interest me - but that's not what OP is asking about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers if you reference this question in asking that question, you could hence make it clear why it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of this one. Or answer this one, and add information on that if you have it.

Comment: @Jon: [Use of **gerund complements** has been on the increase ever since the Middle English period](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gerund+complements+has+been+on+the+increase%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2):

All three are valid.

The first two use the gerund *playing* to allow us to use the verb *play* as we would a noun.

The last uses the noun *play*. While clearly the noun *play* is related to the verb *play*, they are quite separate uses. A telling contrast is if we were talking about people enjoying eating food; we would be picking between "enjoy eating" and "enjoy food" and not considering "enjoy eat" or "enjoy fooding".

The first uses the axillary *do*. It's not necessary, but not incorrect either.

There are a few reasons why we might strongly favour one or other in a given case. For example if we were adding to, contrasting with or contradicting a use of a noun we would favour the last as it also uses a noun, and likewise we'd reply to a verb with a verb:

> "Parents enjoy quiet".
>
> "What parents enjoy is play with their children".
>
> "Parents enjoy getting a break".
>
> What parents enjoy [doing] is playing with their children". [This bit applies to both the form with and without doing].

We might favour the *doing* from to emphasise that we are talking about an activity engaged in by parents if we already had a context of activities engaged in by parents. E.g.:

> "Parents enjoy having a break from the chaos of dealing with children."
>
> "What parents enjoy doing is playing with their children."

Here the *doing* emphasises that we are contrasting this with another thing parents could be doing.

These though are just minor reasons to favour one or another to chime well with another use. All of them could be used perfectly well in any of the cases above. (There are some other sentences where using "do-support" might seem strange in some contexts, but the "What…" in each of these means it's always reasonable).

From your comment:

> What parents enjoy doing is play with their children.

This isn't correct because here *play* is either the verb, in which case it's the wrong part of the verb, (compare with "what I enjoy doing is eat" which uses *eat* in the same way) or else it is the noun, in which case it's used where nouns don't belong because "doing" has told the audience there'll be a verb to describe what is done, (comapre with "what I enjoy doing is food" which uses *food* in the same way).

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, they are all correct. But in terms of frequent usage,
your second one is most common (at least in parenting social groups
in December of 2014) (personal communication, 2014).

It depends on who your listening "audience" is, I guess. But, as above,
your # 2 is "best" to answer your question if you are just chatting with
other English-speaking parents.